# Deja-Dup backup to Readyshare fails

Tags: samba, 17.10, ftp, deja-dup

I am trying to backup to a Readyshare USB drive using Deja-Dup 36.6 in Ubuntu 17.10 on Xorg. Using ftp:// I simply get an "Operation Failed" message. Using smb:// I get to the Password/Domain menu then I get "Failed to mount Windows share: No such file or directory" Reading other posts has not helped nor has the help. I have double checked and re-entered the address and file information many times. My goal is to alternate backups to to both my external drive (works well) and the readyshare drive.

Comment: Correction DejaDup 36.2

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I tried using FTP, but it did not work, the same connection in FileZilla worked.

But I found the solution:
Use as location "Custom Location".
And type after URI `smb://readyshare/"share-name`.
Share-name is the name you have set in the router.